# I want create search engine like Google, which search engine should I use?

Tags: solr, search-engine, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I want create a search engine like google. Which search engine should I use? Does solr or elasticsearch suitable for that?

Comment: I knew that there are similar questions [Which third party search engine (free) should I use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932697/which-third-party-search-engine-free-should-i-use) [Which open-source search engine should be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418372/which-open-source-search-engine-should-be-used),but I want create a search engine like google. we have different goal. That should be a new discussion.

Comment: hey guys, Why downvote without any discussion?

Comment: Because this isn´t a discussion board. Read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask for more information. There is a discussion chat though, check it: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: That should be a new question either. Anyway, thx Christian Lendel. stackoverflow is a nice place. and I really want to get help about my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/) is a good starting point. Especially because it includes crawling as well and uses Lucene. Lucene is also used in Solr and the newest version has the nice [SolrCloud](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud/) feature for easier scalability.

Answer (score 1):

*(Disclosure: The author of this post is affiliated with the product being linked to)*

I would also suggest [OpenSearchServer](http://www.open-search-server.com). The web crawler is mature. We use it to index thousand of web sites on a single instance.

The major point is that it includes the web crawler and the search engine in one single application. With the interface you can set up your data model, customize the relevance, manage the crawl process.